# javascript ream.close() not closing, stopped

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using Realm Database to store data for page navigation in my react native application.The below method stops working after I invoke realm.close()

Can you please suggest me what might be the issue.

```
export const getStorageProtags =  () => {
  return Realm.open({
  schema: [ProtagsSchema]
  }).then(realm => {
    const protags = realm.objects('Protags');
    realm.close();
    return protags[0]; 
 });
}
```

Comment: what exactly not working? exception?

Comment: It hangs no execution after realm.close(). may be in the backend it stopped working.Is it working for you ? I am invoking in react native.